# Multiple points openlayer and only show the last

Tags: openlayers

Please help me with this problem.

I have a route finder that shows both a list and map the various points by which a vehicle has passed. When I click on an item in the list, the point can be seen in the map, but when I have two points in the same location (eg point1, point2), only shows me the last point (point2)

I have no idea how to do that when I click the point1 this point is placed above the point2 and vice versa

My code is:

```
// When I clic in a item of the list
function searchPoint(x, y, zoom) {

if (x != 0 && x != '0' && x != '0.0') {
    map.setCenter(
    new OpenLayers.LonLat(x, y).transform(
            new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
            map.getProjectionObject()
        ), zoom
    );
}
}

layerRutasPuntosHistorial = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Rutas Puntos Historial", {
    //rendererOptions: { zIndexing: true },
    strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
    protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
        url: "trackWeb.asmx/obtenerRutasPuntosHistorial",
        readWithPOST: true,
        params: { idDispositivo: $("#ddlDispositivos").val(), tipo: $(".datavalor.active").attr("data-valor"), fechaInicial: $("#txtFechaDesde").val(), fechaFinal: $("#txtFechaHasta").val() },
        //params: { idDispositivo: $("#ddlDispositivos").val(), tipo: $(".btnTile.selectDates.selected").attr("data-valor"), fechaInicial: $("#txtFechaDesde").val() + " " + $("#ddHoraIn").val() + ":" + $("#ddMinutoIn").val() + ":00", fechaFinal: $("#txtFechaHasta").val() + " " + $("#ddHoraOut").val() + ":" + $("#ddMinutoOut").val() + ":00" },
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8" },
        format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON(),
        contentType: 'application/json; utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: true
    }),
    styleMap: stylesRutas
});


var stylesRutas = new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
    "default": new OpenLayers.Style(null, {
        rules: [
        new OpenLayers.Rule({
            symbolizer: {
                "Point": {
                    pointRadius: 6,
                    graphicName: "circle",
                    fillColor: "#F78F1E",
                    fillOpacity: 1,
                    strokeColor: "#F78F1E",
                    labelOutlineColor: "#F78F1E",
                    cursor: "pointer",
                    label: "${numero}",
                    fontColor: "#fff",
                    fontOpacity: 1,
                    fontFamily: "Arial",
                    fontSize: 9,
                    fontWeight: "600",
                    //graphicZIndex: 10,
                    //labelZIndex: 10,

                    //graphicZIndex : 9999999,
                    //zIndex: 99999999,
                }
            }
        })
        ]
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking by x,y inside a geoJson file. Logically, computer would find and render items in the order that they were retrieved, point1 first, point2 second. Since you are not providing any names to the computer, there is no way for the computer to understand which point exactly you want.

Example set: `{{x,y},{x,y},{a,b},{c,d},{e,f}}`

Now you are asking computer to get `{x,y}`

How does it know, which one you want? It doesn't. One `{x,y}` is no different than the other, as far as it knows.

You could reverse sort the geoJSON file, but then you are likely to run into the reverse of your situation, where you would want to display the second point rather than the first one. But if you don't care about that - just reverse sort geoJSON.